# preventing adding suffix (.1) to instance name after CUT and PAST in Catia vb script

Tags: vba, catia

I am preforming task that reordering the Catia tree using instance name. Script executing well without errors. I used cut and paste method in the script to achieve task.

```vb
selection1.Cut
Set selection2 = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
selection2.Add product1
selection2.Paste
selection1.Clear
selection2.Clear
```

my problem is after pasting .1,.2 suffix are adding to pasted elements.
ex: before cut instance name was (XMA1_2).
After pasting instance name will be  (XMA1_2.1)

added suffix to instance name will be big problem form me. if any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can rename the instance after pasting it. But I assume that the instance name must be unique (so a suffix is useful)

Comment: the problem is i have some part names "CHT12456.15" etc. For those parts i should not rename because it does not add suffix like "CHT12456.15.1" when i pasting it.

Comment: So you could check the instance name (or even better the name/partnumber of the ReferenceProduct) before cut the instance.

Comment: I got it, now it is not adding suffix. I have done this way. before cut the selection1 I store the name in one variable and after pasting I renamed the selction1 with the variable where the original name stored. thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Hello, i suggest you to use windows automation to use directly thé Catia function instead of copy/paste. Start command "Graph tree reordering" and then use bytes to UP/down your products.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. but in tree list hundreds of parts are there it will take more time to sort manually by using "Graph tree reordering" selecting the part and using up down buttons. but in above method it will take only few seconds .

Comment: Using graph tree reordering is a lot of faster than copy paste. You can easily select your product of thé window, and replace with position of other one. Thé feature will not copy/paste your instances. Sée a sample there (Don't pay attention to Excel) using the windows automation with graph tree reordering : https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=416671

Comment: In this "Graph tree reordering" method can we sort all tree list with one click ? or we need to select which parts has to sort ?.

Comment: You can sort your tree by Alphanumeric with your own algorithm using ui windows automation. Tak a look in the link above. You dont even need to set design mode on your mockup.